# How to fix console errors on component start

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have an issue with one of my project component. When the app start I call the 
the "getAboutMeById" function  to get the user details and on the "site-header.component.ts" I get the following errors in the console, but i can see the image after the page finished loading.

I tried putting the data as is in the service, but I got the same results

the component:

```
export class SiteHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  aboutMe: AboutMe = null;
  year: number = new Date().getFullYear();
  @Output() navigationClickFired = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor(private moranmonoService: MoranMonoService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAboutMeById(1);
  }
  getAboutMeById(id: number) {
    this.moranmonoService.GetAboutMeById(id).subscribe(res => {
      let result = <AboutMe>res;
      if (result != null) {
        this.aboutMe = new AboutMe(result.name, result.emailAddress, result.phoneNumber, result.homeAddress, result.profilePhotoUrl,
          result.profession, result.introduction, result.cvFileUrl, result.experience);
      } else {
        console.log('AboutMeComponent | getAboutMeById: Encountered an error.', result);
      }
    });
  }
  onNavigationClick(linkName: string) {
    this.navigationClickFired.emit(linkName);
  }
}
```

The html code:

```
<header id="site_header" class="header mobile-menu-hide">
  <div class="header-content clearfix">
    <div class="my-photo">
      <img src="{{aboutMe.profilePhotoUrl}}" alt="image" class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 100px">
    </div>
    <div class="site-title-block">
      <div class="site-title">{{ aboutMe.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-nav">
      <ul id="nav" class="site-main-menu">
        <li>
          <a class="pt-trigger" (click)="onNavigationClick('AboutMe')" href="#about-me">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="pt-trigger" (click)="onNavigationClick('Resume')" href="#resume">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <!-- <li>
      <a class="pt-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="pt-trigger" href="#blog">Blog</a>
    </li> -->
        <li>
          <a class="pt-trigger" (click)="onNavigationClick('Contact')" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="copyrights">All rights {{ year }}</div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="mobile-header mobile-visible">
  <div class="mobile-logo-container">
    <div class="mobile-header-image">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="{{aboutMe.profilePhotoUrl}}" alt="image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-site-title"><a href="#">{{aboutMe.name}}</a></div>
  </div>

  <a class="menu-toggle mobile-visible">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="lmpixels-arrows-nav">
  <div class="lmpixels-arrow-left"><i class="lnr lnr-chevron-left"></i></div>
  <div class="lmpixels-arrow-right"><i class="lnr lnr-chevron-right"></i></div>
</div>
```

the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoranMonoService {
  baseurl = environment.baseURL;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  GetAboutMeById(id: number) {
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    reqHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseurl + 'api/AboutMe/get-aboutme-byId?id=' + id, { headers: reqHeader });
  }
  GetResumeEntities() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseurl + 'api/Resume/get-resume-entites');
  }
  GetExperienceEntities() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseurl + 'api/Experience/get-expirence-entites');
  }
  SendEmail(contact: Contact) {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseurl + 'api/contact/send-email', contact);
  }
}
```

I want the image to load without the errors, instead I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'profilePhotoUrl' of null
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SiteHeaderComponent.html:29)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11080)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10456)
at callViewAction (core.js:10692)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10457)
at callViewAction (core.js:10692)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10457)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
```

Comment: `console.log(result)` inside subscribe? or might be you will need this: `*ngIf="aboutMe"` then `aboutMe.profilePhotoUrl`

Comment: The problem is inside the SiteHeaderComponent.html. Could you attach it?

Comment: The problem you is at SiteHeaderComponent.html line 29 please add your code

Comment: I added the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your html file of your SiteHeader component is trying to access the aboutMe variable while your service dit not yet load the data. Waiting for the data to be uploaded, your aboutMe variable is still in is initial state, which is null.

If the error is about the 'profilePhotoUrl' property it's because it muse be the first to be required in your html file.

The solution would be to wrap all the html elements based on the aboutMe variable in a  element with a *ngIf inside

```
<div *ngIf="aboutMe">
  <img src="aboutMe.profilePhotoUrl" />
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this the only solution, do you know why this is happening? Is this a common thing?

Comment: In javascript it's effectively a very common error. It's because of it's asynchronous nature. When your component siteHeader is calling the service for loading the data, it's not waiting for the data to be loaded for rendering the component. It keep going, even if your observable did not finnish it's mission. There are effectively other ways to deal with it, but this one is the most used.